# Enqueue a stylesheet for login page and make it appear in head element

Tags: theme-development, css, login, wp-enqueue-style

I try to style the login page in my theme. Very simple:

```
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', function()
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'TEST', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/login.css' );
});
```

Unfortunately, it doesn’t work as expected. The `link` element appears in the `body` of the login page, very late.

Rendered output:

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' id='TEST-css'  href='http://themes.wp/t5-theme-base/css/login.css?ver=3.9-alpha' type='text/css' media='all' />
<div class="clear"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is wrong, how can I print the link element in the `head`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For every `enqueue` action, there is a corresponding `print_styles` action:

- `wp_enqueue_scripts` → `wp_print_styles`
- `admin_enqueue_scripts` → `admin_print_styles`
- `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` → `customize_controls_print_styles`

Not for the login page. There is no `login_print_styles` action or function, so your stylesheets are thrown out on `do_action( 'login_footer' );`.

But there is a simple fix:

```
if ( ! has_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_print_styles' ) )
    add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_print_styles', 11 );
```

WordPress will now print all `link` elements registered for that page at the proper place, the `head` element, right after the built-in stylesheets.

Result:

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://git.wp/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=3.9-alpha' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-admin-css'  href='http://git.wp/wp-admin/css/wp-admin.min.css?ver=3.9-alpha' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='buttons-css'  href='http://git.wp/wp-includes/css/buttons.min.css?ver=3.9-alpha' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='colors-fresh-css'  href='http://git.wp/wp-admin/css/colors.min.css?ver=3.9-alpha' type='text/css' media='all' />
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='ie-css'  href='http://git.wp/wp-admin/css/ie.min.css?ver=3.9-alpha' type='text/css' media='all' />
<![endif]-->
<link rel='stylesheet' id='TEST-css'  href='http://themes.wp/t5-theme-base/css/login.css?ver=3.9-alpha' type='text/css' media='all' />
```