# WordPress Register Style Called Incorrectly

Tags: css, hooks, wp-register-style

Why am I getting this error?

```
Notice: wp_register_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /var/www/domain.com/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3792
```

The code I'm using to include my custom CSS and JS files is:

```
// Register a custom style and script.
wp_register_style( 'custom_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.css' );
wp_register_script( 'custom_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.js', array('jquery') );

// Enqueue a custom style and script in pages and posts.
function add_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_scripts', 9999 );
```

Edit:
Per Pieter's answer, I changed my code to this and it fixed the problem:

```
function add_custom_scripts() {
    // Start "Add Custom Scripts."
    wp_register_style( 'custom_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.css' );
    wp_register_script( 'custom_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.js', array('jquery') );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_scripts', 9999 );

function add_custom_scripts_login() {
    // Start "Add Custom Scripts."
    wp_register_style( 'custom_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.css' );
    wp_register_script( 'custom_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.js', array('jquery') );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js' );
}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_scripts_login', 9999 );
```

Comment: Check please [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137104/wp-enqueue-script-was-called-incorrectly)

It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notice is quite obvious. It is telling you that you are not running `wp_register_style()` within the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.

### SOLUTION

Move your `wp_register_script()` and `wp_register_style()` calls to inside your function which is hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts`

Comment: Shouldn't he move `wp_register_style` and `wp_register_script` inside the function rather than `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style` since they are already in the function?

Comment: denis is right, but thanks anyway, Pieter, for the lead.

Comment: @GTSJoe jip, sorry, silly mistake. But you get the drift. Glad it helped, enjoy ;-)