# How to Access a file that is inside a plugin's dir from the theme's `functions.php` file

Tags: plugins, themes

So basically I am trying to call a stylesheet file from a plugin's directory from the theme's functions.php file as follow:

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/wp-content/plugins/path/to/the/file/style.min.css',false,'1','all');
});
```

I found the previous snippet in this answer here: [wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137104/wp-enqueue-script-was-called-incorrectly#answer-374364)

But it is actually trying to find the file in this path: `wp-content/themes/theme_name/wp-content/plugins/path/to/the/file/style.min.css?ver=1`

Expected Behavior is: `wp-content/plugins/path/to/the/file/style.min.css?ver=1`

I am trying to do that because in the console the file is missing because the wrong path it's trying to access this path: `/ontent/plugins/path/to/the/file/style.min.css?ver=1`

so how I could modify this path to the one I want

Comment: Well get_template_directory_uri() is the path to the theme, so start by removing that…

Comment: @JacobPeattie Silly me, that is right i should have specify my own path i want to access. Thanks for the help.