# Is there any reason why there's no "login_header" action at the login page?

Tags: login, actions

There is a `login_footer` action hook at the `wp-login.php` of Wordpress which is quite handy for strapping in the theme footer into the login/registration page:

```
add_action( 'login_footer', function() {
    get_footer();
});
```

Is there a reason why there is no similar action for header?

Answer (score 0):

There is:

```
/**
 * Fires in the login page header after scripts are enqueued.
 *
 * @since 2.1.0
 */
do_action( 'login_head' );
```

See the function `login_header()` in `wp-login.php`.

What **is** missing is an [action `login_print_styles`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127835/enqueue-a-stylesheet-for-login-page-and-make-it-appear-in-head-element).

Comment: This is definitely not what I mean as `login_head` fires before `<body>` is printed out.