# Are login functions considered part of the WP backend?

Tags: login, user-registration

This might be a dumb question but are the login part of WordPress considered to be part of the backend?

Comment: Yes, I think. You want to clarify the question? What do you mean by "deal with"?

Comment: @s_ha_dum does it belong to the backend part of wp?

Answer (score 1):

These pages are accessible for users who are neither *identified* nor *authenticated*, so they are part of the frontend.

They have no place in the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), but you can style them in your theme, [add custom CSS](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/127835/73) and even nav menus.

By default, they look a little bit like the backend style. That's just because that's the only style WordPress "knows" by default, so this is done for consistency, not to indicate that they actually *are* the backend.

The small overlay that pops up when your session expires while you are using the backend is a special case and indeed part of the backend. It is currently built of the regular login page, so you have to exclude that case in your customizations.